# IOS - Downloading Images From Parse.com Backend

Tags: android, ios, xcode, uiimage, parse-platform

orI have an app that is consistently downloading large images from a parse back-end.  In android you can download the images as streams using their URI's and set a specific dimension size to the bitmap that I want to download.  Usually this is done using the BitmapFactory libraries and allows me to download a bitmap that's of a scaled down size, saving my app from long loading times. Is there an equivalency to this method on the IOS platform?  This is what I am currently doing, but when I download 15 full sized images I get a large amount of load time:

```
//where photoQuery is a Parse.com database query that returns the photo as the first object
PFObject *photoObject = [photoQuery getFirstObject];
PFFile *photoFile = (PFFile *)[photoObject objectForKey:@"fullSizedImage"];

UIImage *fullImage = [UIImage imageWithData:photoFile.getData];
```

Does IOS support something similar to BitmapFactory or this common android design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PFFile` has a method called `– getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:`. Which can be used like this:

```
[photoFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
}
```

Or you can use another method called `- getDataStreamInBackgroundWithBlock:`. It is similar as the one above. The difference is the first parameter of the block is a `NSInputStream`

Answer (score 0):

PFImageView should help you load these images a synchronously. You may try thumbnailing images using Cloud Code.