# Trying to set UIImage from parse class

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uiimage

I have a class called "images" on my parse.com app, this class has a column called "imageFile" which contains a .png image, what I'm wondering is how do i set parseImage to be the image taken in from parse. This is what I have so far.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"images"];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Retrieved data");

    if (!error) {
        PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];

        [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                parseImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                // image can now be set on a UIImageView
            }
        }];
        //parseImage.file = file;

        //[imageHolder loadInBackground];
    }
}];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS - Downloading Images From Parse.com Backend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478329/ios-downloading-images-from-parse-com-backend)

Comment: This one is for objective-c iOS development, that link is for android, but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: it's not for android the answer code syntax is for iOS and the correct answer. try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
parseImage.file = file;
[parseImage loadInBackground];
```

`PFImageView` loads asynchronously. Use that instead of manually retrieving the file.